# Cabal sandbox depends on unrelated packages?

Tags: haskell, cabal

My package has the following dependency which I manage using cabal sandbox:

```
  build-depends:       tagsoup >= 0.13,
                       bytestring >= 0.10.0.2,
                       base >=4.6 && <4.7, attoparsec >=0.12 && <0.13, text >=0.11.2 && <1.2,
                       pipes >= 4.1.2, pipes-attoparsec >= 0.5.1
```

Everything works perfectly till here. Now, I want to use some functionality from package `pipes-text`, so I add the following rule to it:

```
pipes-text
```

I don't explicitly put any version so as to allow the cabal to be flexible enough to choose some sane version. Once it chooses that, I will include that constraint in the `build-depends` section.

I give the following command to install the dependencies in my sandbox:

```
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' is 26 days old.
Run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages.
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
blaze-builder-0.3.3.2 (reinstall) changes: text-0.11.2.3 -> 1.1.1.3
comonad-4.2 (new version)
parsec-3.1.5 (new version)
network-2.5.0.0 (new version)
pipes-safe-2.2.0 (new package)
semigroupoids-4.0.2.1 (new version)
bifunctors-4.1.1.1 (new version)
profunctors-4.0.4 (new version)
free-4.9 (new version)
pipes-group-1.0.0 (new package)
pipes-bytestring-2.0.1 (new package)
streaming-commons-0.1.3 (reinstall) changes: network-2.4.0.1 -> 2.5.0.0,
text-0.11.2.3 -> 1.1.1.3
pipes-text-0.0.0.11 (new package)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
conduit-extra-1.1.0.4
conduit-combinators-0.2.5.2
mime-mail-0.4.3
language-javascript-0.5.8
hjsmin-0.1.4.4
http-types-0.8.3
http-client-multipart-0.2.0.0
http-client-0.2.2.2
http-client-tls-0.2.1.1
hamlet-1.1.7.6
fast-logger-2.1.0
cookie-0.4.0.1
chunked-data-0.1.0.1
blaze-markup-0.5.1.6
blaze-html-0.6.1.2
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

Now this confuses me, I haven't installed any conduit related libraries within the sandbox. So why is the cabal worried about that ? Any pointers on avoid this problem ?

Comment: Have you installed conduit related libraries globally?

Comment: Try to add -v3 to cabal install to get some more information on why conduit is involved.

Comment: @bennofs Yes, conduit is installed globally. I will debug it further and add more information here as tibbe suggested.

Comment: The warning about broken packages predates the presence of sandboxes. One can argue that if sandbox packages possibly "break" global packages, this shouldn't be warned about, because one can easily step outside of the sandbox and the packages will still work.

Comment: @tibbe This is the output: https://gist.github.com/psibi/39d398ef57c277635cb6